# Add new domain to existing letsencrypt ssl?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt, server-configuration

I have added my domain in letsencrypt ssl without www.[domain] when I was creating it. now want to add with www.[domain]. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is exact same question on LE forum: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/adding-a-new-domain-name-to-existing-cert/10992